# Differences between various distributed computing primitives

Tags: distributed-computing, blocking, nonblocking

I am trying to understand the primitive concepts of distributed computing from the book Distributed Computing - Principles, Algorithms and Systems by cambridge university press. I encounter an illustration which discuss the differences between

```
Blocking/Non-blocking Synchronous/Asynchronous systems
```

[image]as shown in the figure below which I couldn't understand.

Can someone with this knowledge help me understand the conceptual differences between them with some examples?

Comment: Note time goes left to right.

Comment: @DanD. I get that and I understand the difference between Blocking and non-blocking. Are synchronous/blocking and asynchronous/non-blocking similar to each other?

Comment: Those pairs are tightly related. You can't have asynchronous/blocking or synchronous/non-blocking.

Comment: Synchronous/asynchronous implies blocking/non-blocking but not vice versa

Comment: Can real life examples be stated to contrast the four categories? From my understanding, smtp/http belong to synchronous blocking, email belongs to asynchronous non-blocking asynchronous. Am i on the right track?